# Passing an array of pointers and return an array of values pointed by those pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I want to write a function that passes an array of `n` pointers to `float` and returns a newly created array that contains those `n` `float` values. Here is the code:

```
float* duplicate(float* p[], int n){
    float* const b = new float[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i] = *p[i];
    return b;
}
```

My question is that why should we declare `b` as **`const`**? If I remove `const`, how is the result be affected? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By using the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html), the variable `b` is a constant pointer to `float`, meaning that the pointer is constant and you can't change it.

Comment: The code is invalid, I think you meant `return b;`. Making `b` a `const` pointer doesn't make any difference in this case, and the code is terrible whether you do that or not. Use `std::vector<float>` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it is a typo. It is  return b; . Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: To clarify, each pointer in `p` just points to a single float? (not the first float of an array) ?

Comment: @Praetorian Why should they use  a vector instead ?

Comment: @JID Read the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27979645/241631) below.

Comment: @Praetorian so just preference ?

Comment: @JID When handling memory allocation yourself, there's quite a high chance that you'll get it wrong. It's one of those things that experience tells us is best hidden away in a well tested library.

Answer (score 4):

Declaring `b` as

```
float* b = ...;
```

will work equally well here. The `const` means that the pointer stored in `b` (that points to the beginning of the array of `float`s) cannot be changed.

Since the code doesn't try to change it anyway (it would fail to compile if it tried), removing the `const` would make no difference.

The `const` is there as a sort of safety mechanism. The programmer is asking the compiler "tell me off if I try to do something stupid with this variable". As a general rule, it is a good idea to make things `const` by default, unless you actually know you need to change them. This means you won't accidentally assign to something you didn't mean to, leaving you with a possibly hard to track down bug.

(There may also be an argument that the compiler has more optimisation opportunities with `const`. Maybe this is true in some cases, but it's somewhat irrelevant here. Safety is the main concern in this case.)

But in this case, all that manual memory management and mucking about with pointers is asking for trouble anyway, you'd be better off using a library component that does all that for you, such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Edit: Just for completeness, here's a version using `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<float> duplicate(float* f[], std::size_t n)
{
    std::vector<float> copyOfF;
    copyOfF.reserve(n); // save enough space; not essential
    std::transform(f, // front of f
                   f+n, // back of f
                   std::back_inserter(copyOfF), // push them into the vector
                   [](float* f){return *f;} ); // deref the pointers
    return copyOfF; // will steal the internal array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`const` in `float* const b` means that pointer can't be changed. For example, this will fail to compile :

```
float* const b;
```

In your case, nothing will change if you remove const.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a variable `const`, you *cannot* change its value after the initialization.

So, when you write:

> ```
> float* const b = new float[n];
> ```

you are telling the compiler that the content of `b` won't be changed in next lines of code. And, if for some reasons, you change it (e.g. via a reassignment of the `b` variable) you will get a compiler error.

You can think of `const` as *"read-only"*, i.e. the value of `b` (which is the address returned by the `new[]` call) *cannot* be changed in following lines of code.

Note that you *can* change the *content of the array* allocated by `new[]`! In fact, as written your code, the `const` applies only to the value of `b` (i.e. the memory address returned by `new[]`), not to the content of the array *pointed to* by `b`.

Note that, instead, if you write code like this:

```
const float* b = ...
```

then, this is completely different. In fact, in this case, you can change the value of `b`, e.g. you can reassign `b` to point to something else, *but* you *cannot* change the *content of the array* pointed to by `b`.

And you can also combine the effects of the two `const`s, e.g.

```
const float * const b = ...
```

In this case, you *cannot* change either the value of `b` (i.e. you can't reassign `b`) or the content of the array pointed to by `b`.

Of course, in your case, since you want to write some content into the array allocated with `new[]`, it does make sense to just use `const` for the value of `b` (the pointer), not for the array pointed to. In other words, the array pointed to by `b` should be read/write (i.e. non-`const`), not read-only (i.e. `const`).

---

**NOTE:** In modern C++, it's usually better to use some *container class*, like `std::vector`, instead of allocating memory with raw `new[]`.
(One of the advantages of using `std::vector` is that the memory and resources stored in the `vector` are *automatically* released thanks to vector's destructor.)

So, unless this is a learning experiment code, or you have strong reasons to use `new[]`, consider using `std::vector` for dynamically allocated arrays in modern C++.